# Java Extract data from JSON Array

Tags: java, arrays, json

Below is the json format, I have to extract the data of dynamic key-value pair.

```
{"data": [
         {"1000":"2018-03-10 00:00:00.0"},
         {"100031": "2018-03-15"}
         ]
}
```

This is something I am trying but its not working and showing errors:

In input, I am getting the JSON object.

```
JSONArray lastdtArr =   json.getJSONArray("data");
int len = lastdtArr.length();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    JSONObject lastdtid = lastdtArr.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = lastdtid.getKey();
    String date = lastdtid.getValue();
    //Operations to perform
}
```

PS: I am completely new to Java. The solutions I find over internet are for the json format where key is fixed in key-value pair. But in this case, key is always dynamic. Please let me know what all I have to write inside the loop for getting the values in id and date?

Comment: You should have a look at one of the thousands of tutorials out there covering this exact problem.

Comment: @Ben Indeed. It's probably a /meta, but even if our job as been defined and redifined thousands times as helpers, that's not a bad thing to come here seeking for some teaching with a specific problem as described in the [ask] page. On top of the fact that most of the code newbies searching for help here will also be in need of some teaching no matter how you look at it :). I think  sharing raw knowledge can't be a bad thing, as a brilliant scientist said one day: If i give you knowledge i'am not losing anything, i'am just creating something new from the addition of yours and mine :)

Comment: @xoxel I am not sure what you are trying to tell me, sorry.

Comment: I don't see how i could explain myself better, just for the resume: ofc he should have looked by himself, but that doesn't mean whe shouldn't help him out.

Comment: Now I got it. He has been on SO for close to 6 years and asked a question that just by inputting the exact title in the search bar here gives 40 other results. There is a limit to where giving advice is suitable over pointing out that the very basics of asking a question here (do some research first, use the search bar, show us what you have tried, etc.) have not been fulfilled. Even more so for a veteran member.

Comment: @ben, true i assumed he was a newbie without looking at his rep.

Comment: @Ben, everywhere i found solution where json object has names of the fields. In my case, i am not able to retrieve values of dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSONArray to extract your Data as it is an ARRAY of OBJECT, then you can iterate on it using JSONObject to acces each object in this array, here is a quick guide i wrote a couple months ago:

```
What is a JSON object : (just to be clear) A .json file contains text-based representations of data structures and objects. A JSON object is delimited by "{" and "}" and represent a single object/structure inside a .json file.

JSONObject : It's a type representing a single JSON object in JAVA.

JSONArray : Seems obvious, but it's an array wich contains JSONObject elements, 
            i recommend you to use this to keep your objects packed into an array,
            this type is providing a lot of usefull methods aswell as JSONObject does,
            i'll list some of them below it's up to you to search for the others. 

JSONArray.getJSONObject(index) : Pass it an index and it will return the JSONObject stored 
                                 at this index.
JSONArray.put([value] | [index, value]) : This might be extremly straightforward but it's actually pretty 
                       usefull if you want to build a JSONArray, pass it a JSONObject 
                       or another common type (int, String, etc) and it will add it to 
                       your JSONArray. 
                       Depending on what you pass it you'll need an index aswell.

JSONObject.keys() : Returns an iterator of the String names in your JSONObject.

JSONObject.put(name, value) : Create a field in your JSONObject using the name you passed 
                              and assigning the value to it.

JSONObject.getString(name) : Pass the name of a field to it and it will return 
                             it's value as a String. As you may have guess already, there is a couple of those, not only getString().
```

The rest is up to you.

Comment: Thanks xoxel. As you see I dont have names of the fields. Key is integer and dynamic. Hence i am unable to retrieve the values.